# Corda Exception - com.sc.corda.server.exception.CordaFlowException

Tags: exception, deployment, corda

I am new to Corda and this is my first post.
Sometimes after new clean deployment - I am facing issues in Corda. Where a certai

```html
[ERROR] 2018-09-26T06:26:00,545 [http-nio-3034-exec-7] ExposureController - com.sc.corda.node.exception.SCFlowException: Unable to Notarize Security Transactions! SignedTransaction(id=42F7307C39AA5B027E087D92934955D0D8EC2AECB0B41C23E98B537DCB14837F) [[13BC1048B86C401A5850F0E4169487F03C6AA7813FAFD9E3F1AC9729AFEEA094A86B8FCB8459729CC7F09AE379AE353DA3EADC9518D569E695F337B69909B10C]]
[ERROR] 2018-09-26T06:26:00,563 [http-nio-3034-exec-7] [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sc.corda.server.exception.CordaFlowException: com.sc.corda.node.exception.SCFlowException: Unable to Notarize Security Transactions! SignedTransaction(id=42F7307C39AA5B027E087D92934955D0D8EC2AECB0B41C23E98B537DCB14837F) [[13BC1048B86C401A5850F0E4169487F03C6AA7813FAFD9E3F1AC9729AFEEA094A86B8FCB8459729CC7F09AE379AE353DA3EADC9518D569E695F337B69909B10C]]] with root cause
com.sc.corda.server.exception.CordaFlowException: com.sc.corda.node.exception.SCFlowException: Unable to Notarize Security Transactions! SignedTransaction(id=42F7307C39AA5B027E087D92934955D0D8EC2AECB0B41C23E98B537DCB14837F) [[13BC1048B86C401A5850F0E4169487F03C6AA7813FAFD9E3F1AC9729AFEEA094A86B8FCB8459729CC7F09AE379AE353DA3EADC9518D569E695F337B69909B10C]]
 at com.sc.corda.server.controller.ExposureController.allocateAutomatedExposure(ExposureController.java:666) ~[classes!/:?]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
```

n functionality was working as per requirement initially but after a new deployment or incase there is no activity on server for couple of days then I start getting exceptions or the Flows don't work as expected.
I am getting following exception currently- com.sc.corda.server.exception.CordaFlowException: com.sc.corda.node.exception.SCFlowException: Unable to Notarize Security Transactions!
Attached file has the complete exception.Could anyone help me find a solution to

Comment: That's not one of our exception messages, it's one of yours. Can you post the flow code and full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

`com.sc.corda.server` is not one of Corda's error prefix. And `Unable to Notarize Security Transactions!` is not one of Corda's error message.

It is generated by the server you had implemented. My guess is that your server try to initiate a flow, but the flow failed with your customized error message stating that it is unable to notarize security transactions.